# Rails 4 or 5, stale or fresh_when methods with includes in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, caching, rails-activerecord

I'm using Rails 5 with this:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
  fresh_when(etag: @posts, last_modified: @posts.maximum(:updated_at))
end
```

and this is the Rails log:

```
(1.0ms)  SELECT MAX("posts"."updated_at") FROM "posts"
(0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS "size", MAX("posts"."updated_at") AS timestamp FROM "posts"
```

but what if I have a query like this:

```
@posts = Post.includes(:comments).all
```

The Rails's log is:

```
Started GET "/posts"
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
   (0.2ms)  SELECT MAX("posts"."updated_at") FROM "posts" LEFT OUTER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."post_id" = "posts"."id"
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS "size", MAX("posts"."updated_at") AS timestamp FROM "posts"
```

but anything for comments. And indeed if I modify a single comment of that post and "updated_at" column changes it doesn't update the query.

How to?

Without "includes(:comments)" everything works good.

Comment: Can you show the rails log without the `includes(:comments)` bit so we can compare the two?

Comment: You are right. Question updated. Thanks.

Comment: Hello I wanted to ask you what is the association between `post` and `comment` modules.

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio, what you mean? Post has many comments...